# How to have multiple parts of a website in one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a website that will have multiple pages, but because of a unique navigation bar, I cannot simply link to a new file for each page. What is the best way to accomplish this. Some possibilities that I can think of are having all of them on one page, but using css and javascript to move the other pages offscreen, or using iframes and loading them with javascript. Could someone please direct me to some examples or tutorials?

Comment: Are you using any serverside programming laguage or do you have static site only?

Comment: Unique navigation bar? Really? I bet one of the many MVC frameworks or Single Page App frameworks out there will solve your problem. There is no real "solution" to this.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan: I am using javascript, html, and css, but I think this can be accomplished without server side

Comment: @epascarello: whats the sarcasm for?

Comment: @epascarello: thanks btw. Single Page App was the google search term I was looking for.

Comment: @stas, generate the navigation bar with javascript/jquery and call them on each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to load up pages as they are clicked from the navigation. Simply have a containing divider (`<div>`) which the page will load into.

This will load the pages without reloading.

IFF (not a typo, it means "If and Only If") you want support for browsers without Javascript enabled, use an iFrame, but then in your javascript remove it from the browser as it's very bad practice to use iFrames.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("iframe").remove();
 $("body").append("<div id='page_container'></div>");
 $("#navigation_bar a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#page_container").load("http://www.example.com/"+this.attr("href"));
 });
});
</script>
```

HTML would look like:

```
<body>
 <nav>
  <a href="link1.html" target="frame">Link1</a>
  <a href="link2.html" target="frame">Link2</a>
 </nav>
 <iframe src="link1.html" name="frame"></iframe>
</body>
```

Not tested, but concept should work (http://jsfiddle.net/Ns2Gx/)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to use iframes.

Set src for each iframe as the page that you want to show in a small div.

This should do it

Comment: So I can simply change the src to a new `.html`. Also, will changing the src remove the resources used by the previous iframe?

Comment: Yes it does, unless you keep references to them in the parent window.